# Is there a VGA to Thunderbolt/mini DisplayPort adapter?

Tags: cinema-display, vga-adapter

I am looking for an adapter to connect my Apple display to a Sony notebook via VGA, so I need the reverse of this one:

[image: Image of Apple mini DisplayPort-to-VGA connector.]

Does such a product exist?

Answer (score 2):

VGA is an analog signal and your Cinema requires digital so you need more than a simple cable. You need an appropriate interface box, called a VGA to DVI Scaler, such as the Gefen [VGA to DVI Scaler Plus](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=4341). (Shown for reference only—this is not a recommendation.)

You will also need the appropriate adaptor to use the DVI signal with your monitor.

*Please note that I don't have experience with these products and can't guarantee results—particularly if your Display is the thunderbolt-equipped model. Contact the vendors to assure yourself that it will work.*

Answer (score 2):

You will need a VGA to DVI scaler ($330 in [mentioned link](http://www.gefen.com/kvm/dproduct.jsp?prod_id=4341)) + DVI to MDP adapter [like this one](http://estore.circuitassembly.com/products/DVI-to-Mini-Displayport-Adapter.html) ($70). And after that no guarantee that it will work all together.